# Show back button in navigation bar

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app, I want to show a back button in the navigation bar, even on Android devices. I tried this:

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to add a back button in the navigation bar for Android devices?

Comment: You want the back button in `MyPage` ?

Comment: Yes. Like how there's a back button at the top-left corner of iOS apps

Comment: The backbuttons should appear automatically, assuming you used `PushAync` .. Is your `MyPage` your `MainPage` also ?

Comment: No it's not, and I use `PushModalAsync`

Comment: Use `PushAsync`, `ModalAsync` does not allow for you to navigate backwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "error" was using `PushModalAsync`

From the docs:
*A modal page encourages users to complete a self-contained task that cannot be navigated away from until the task is completed or cancelled*

So unless you want this kind of behaviour, you use

`PushAsync(...)`